# Help using msg.value and transfer()

Tags: solidity, remix, payable

Im trying to make a transfer ownership example by transferring ownership by sending ether. I've been trying to use msg.value and transfer() to send ether from owner B to owner A so owner B can take ownership.

```
address public previousOwner;
address public currentOwner;
uint public txTimeStamp;
event transferred();

function transfer() external payable onlyOwnerB {
     require (msg.value == 1 ether);
     ownerA.transfer(1 ether);
     previousOwner = ownerA;
     currentOwner = ownerB;
     txTimeStamp = now;
     emit transferred();
}
```

I also have a fallback function to receive funds:

```
function receiveTxPay() public payable returns (bool) {
     return true;
}
```

I'm using the Remix compiler in a Javascript VM, where owner A is one of the addresses and owner B is another. I made sure to call the transfer() function as owner B. But whenever I call the function i get a "transact to Contract.transfer() errored: VM error: revert." error. I've also tried just using the require(msg.value == 1 ether) line, and also just using the transfer() line. Trying all of these returns the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those lines will fail if you haven't sent 1 ether to the contract as part of your transaction, so I assume you're not doing that. You need to set the "value" field in the upper right to 1 ether. (Make sure you type `1` in the text field and choose `ether` from the dropdown to its right.)